# Pandas, adding prefix to values if the original value is less than 3 characters

Tags: pandas

I have a pandas dataframe.
In column cxt all string values should be 4 characters.
Some of theme are 3 or less characters.
In those occasions a number of `'0'`s should be put at the front of the string value.

Currently I'm using code like: `gdf.loc[gdf.cxt == '0', 'cxt'] = '0000'` to catch certain strings.

Also as a cheeky follow on, `gdf.loc[gdf.cxt.string.contains '.', 'cxt'] = '0000'` overwrites all my values, rather than replacing any string with a `'.'` character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you mean `zfill`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'ctx':['0','.x','001', 'abcd']})
df['ctx'].str.zfill(4)
```

Output:

```
0    0000
1    00.x
2    0001
3    abcd
Name: ctx, dtype: object
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `gdf.loc[gdf.cxt.str.contains('\.'), 'cxt'] = '0000'`